# A Business Scenario That involves Date which needs to be converted from Rows to Columns

Tags: sql

I have the below requirment.
I have data stored in the table as in the below format

```
ID  Region  State   Status           StatusDate
PCR1    1   GA      Initial          25-Oct-14
PCR1    1   GA      DM Review        27-Oct-14
PCR1    1   GA      SD Review        29-Oct-14
PCR1    1   GA      Final Review     31-Oct-14
PCR2    1   LA      Initial          25-Sep-14
PCR2    1   LA      DM Review        27-Sep-14
PCR2    1   LA      SD Review        29-Sep-14
PCR2    1   LA      Final Review     30-Sep-14
```

I want to convert the above data to be converted as below

```
ID  Region  State   Status         StartDate    EndDate
PCR1    1   GA      Initial        25-Oct-14    27-Oct-14
PCR1    1   GA      DM Review      27-Oct-14    29-Oct-14
PCR1    1   GA      SD Review      29-Oct-14    31-Oct-14
PCR1    1   GA      Final Review   31-Oct-14    Current Date
PCR2    1   LA      Initial        25-Sep-14    27-Sep-14
PCR2    1   LA      DM Review      27-Sep-14    29-Sep-14
PCR2    1   LA      SD Review      29-Sep-14    30-Sep-14
PCR2    1   LA      Final Review   30-Sep-14    Current Date
```

How this can be accomplished. EnDate is arrived based on the status dat of the next status. For the Final status the end date is Current System Date. Please note that the Status shown above is indicative and it can vary. Thanks in advance for a helpful response

Regards
Anil

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score -1):

In any dbms that supports window functions, you can get something very close pretty simply. I tested this in PostgreSQL, but it's standard SQL, and it will run in current versions of SQL Server and Oracle, too. (With trivial modifications to the INSERT statements.)

```
create table test
  (id char(4) not null, 
   region int not null, 
   state char(2) not null, 
   status varchar(15) not null, 
   statusdate date not null,
   primary key (id, region, state, status)
);

insert into test values
('PCR1', 1, 'GA', 'Initial', '25-Oct-14'),
('PCR1', 1, 'GA', 'DM Review', '27-Oct-14'),
('PCR1', 1, 'GA', 'SD Review', '29-Oct-14'),
('PCR1', 1, 'GA', 'Final Review', '31-Oct-14'),
('PCR2', 1, 'LA', 'Initial', '25-Sep-14'),
('PCR2', 1, 'LA', 'DM Review', '27-Sep-14'),
('PCR2', 1, 'LA', 'SD Review', '29-Sep-14'),
('PCR2', 1, 'LA', 'Final Review', '30-Sep-14');

select id, region, state, status, statusdate,
lead(statusdate) over (partition by id order by statusdate) enddate
from test;
```

```
id    region  state  status        statusdate    enddate
--
PCR1  1       GA     Initial       2014-10-25    2014-10-27
PCR1  1       GA     DM Review     2014-10-27    2014-10-29
PCR1  1       GA     SD Review     2014-10-29    2014-10-31
PCR1  1       GA     Final Review  2014-10-31    
PCR2  1       LA     Initial       2014-09-25    2014-09-27
PCR2  1       LA     DM Review     2014-09-27    2014-09-29
PCR2  1       LA     SD Review     2014-09-29    2014-09-30
PCR2  1       LA     Final Review  2014-09-30
```

You can get the literal value 'Current date' instead of NULL in your output, but I'd think hard about that if I were you. IMHO, that's better handled in application code. But you can rewrite the SQL this way.

```
select id, region, state, status, statusdate, 
       coalesce(cast(enddate as varchar), 'Current date') enddate
from (select id, region, state, status, statusdate,
      lead(statusdate) over (partition by id order by statusdate) enddate
      from test
     ) x
```

```
id    region  state  status        statusdate    enddate
--
PCR1  1       GA     Initial       2014-10-25    2014-10-27
PCR1  1       GA     DM Review     2014-10-27    2014-10-29
PCR1  1       GA     SD Review     2014-10-29    2014-10-31
PCR1  1       GA     Final Review  2014-10-31    Current date
PCR2  1       LA     Initial       2014-09-25    2014-09-27
PCR2  1       LA     DM Review     2014-09-27    2014-09-29
PCR2  1       LA     SD Review     2014-09-29    2014-09-30
PCR2  1       LA     Final Review  2014-09-30    Current date
```

I prefer application code for this kind of output, because in SQL that "enddate" column can't be returned as a column of dates. It has to be returned as a column of varchar.